# How can I iterate through all the key and value of configuration object

Tags: 8, configuration

I have an admin setting form (Configuration form) called 'example.settings'. I can load the configuration using below code.

> $config = \Drupal::config('example.settings');

Is there a way to iterate through and get all the configuration values in this config object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following to get the raw values back:

```
$config->getRawData()
```

E.g. the following

```
$config = \Drupal::config('system.maintenance');
$config->getRawData()
```

Returns and array of something like:
'message' => string(93) "@site is currently under maintenance. We should be back shortly. Thank you for y…"
'langcode' => "en"
→'_core' => array(1)

Comment: Thanks @Leigh, this works

Comment: I could get all the values using `\Drupal::config('system.maintenance')->get()`. By not passing any parameter to the `get()` function.